# mongodb aggregate addFields query (in kotlin + stitch) - multiple documents together not working

Tags: mongodb, kotlin, aggregate

im trying to create a query for mongodb in kotlin with stitch, for adding 2 fields at once using aggregation .
separately it works , but putting both documents together doesnt. 
tried using different list types: listOf, arryListOf, arrayOf, mutableListOf ... nothing works
as well as casting it

code:

```
val aggregationPipeLine = listOf(
    Document("\$addFields", listOf(
        Document("likedCount", Document("\$size", "\$liked")),   //works separately
        Document("dislikedCount", Document("\$size", "\$disliked"))    //works separately
    )
)
```

thnx

Answer (score 0):

worked with:

```
Document("\$addFields", Document("likedPercentage", Document("\$divide", listOf("\$likedCount","\$likeAndDislikeCount"))))
```

not sure what was the initial problem :/